# Passing template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Let's say we have a class called `TypeCollection` that holds a packed template of types:

```
template<typename ...Types>
class TypeCollection {};
```

And if we have a class that templates a `TypeCollection` you would need to do something a little like this:

```
template<template<typename ...> class Collection, typename ...Types>
class CollectionHandler {};
```

Which would be instantiated like so:

```
CollectionHandler<TypeCollecion, A, B, C>
```

This isn't great since we have to pass the types A B and C twice for template deduction.
My question is if there is a way to do this without having to pass the types twice:

```
CollectionHandler<TypeCollecion<A, B, C>>
```

However I cant seem to get this to work. I tried a couple things and I realized that you cant pass a templated class as a parameter:

```
CollectionHandler<TypeCollecion<A, B, C>>  // Error: Template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
```

Is there a way to instantiate `CollectionHandler` without having to pass the types twice? I experimented with tuples to hide the parameters but I couldn't get that to work either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"we have to pass the types `A`, `B` and `C` twice for template deduction"* ? You pass them only once, (and CTAD would also work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flip your `CollectionHandler` declaration around to dissect the `TypeCollection` through template specialization:

```
template <class TypeCollection>
class CollectionHandler;

template <class... Types>
class CollectionHandler<TypeCollection<Types...>> { };
```

Comment: This is the right approach if you want access to `Types...` inside the CollectionHandler.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! Quite easy now that I look at it, should have tested that earlier

Answer (score 3):

`TypeCollecion<A, B, C>` is not a template. It is a type. If you change

```
template<template<typename ...> class Collection, typename ...Types>
class CollectionHandler {};
```

to

```
template<typename Collection>
class CollectionHandler {};
```

Then you can use `TypeCollecion<A, B, C>` as parameter. And `TypeCollection` should probably offer member aliases to access `A`, `B` and `C`.

You do not need a template template parameter when you actually want to use a type as parameter (whether this type is an instantiation of a template does not matter that much).

Comment: Yea that does the trick, thanks for your help! Not as complicated as i initially thought

Comment: Also how would I go about checking if "Collections" is actually a type of class "TypeCollection"? I thought of using decltype but that only works on instances.

Comment: @RedNicStone it wasnt perfectly clear from the question what you actually need, so I only mentioned the most obvious. Perhaps Quentins answer is what you actually want, where `CollectionHandler` is only defined in case the passed type is an instantiation of `TypeCollection` and has direct access to parameters of it